# jSerialComm stops receiving data after a while

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, serial-port, serial-communication

I'm trying to use this library for a JavaFX app that needs to listen 24/7 for messages sent on the serial port, so I'm trying to use the event based reading from jSerialComm with the `RECEIVED` event and a 0x03 (ETX) character delimeter. After running the app on windows 10, after a certain amount of time (sometimes minutes, sometimes hours) the app stops receiving data from the serial port. Am I setting up the classes correctly? This is my MessageListener class:

```
public final class MessageListener implements SerialPortMessageListener{
    private FiseNavController controller;

    @Override
    public int getListeningEvents() { return SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_RECEIVED; }

    @Override
    public byte[] getMessageDelimiter() { return new byte[] { (byte)0x03}; }

    @Override
    public boolean delimiterIndicatesEndOfMessage() { return true; }

    @Override
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event)
    {
        byte[] delimitedMessage = event.getReceivedData();
        String message = new String(delimitedMessage);
        System.out.println("Received the following delimited message: " + message);
    }
}
```

This is how I set up the com port in my main class:

```
    SerialPort[] ports = SerialPort.getCommPorts();
    comPort = ports[ports.length - 1];
    comPort.setComPortParameters(1200, 8, SerialPort.ONE_STOP_BIT, SerialPort.NO_PARITY);
    //comPort.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_SEMI_BLOCKING, 0, 0); --> commented out, not sure if this is needed and it doesn't make any difference
    comPort.openPort();
    MessageListener listener = new MessageListener();
    comPort.addDataListener(listener);
```

Do I also need to clear the buffers every once in a while? Does this have to run on a separate thread?

Comment: At first glance, this looks like a garbage collection issue. Does the listener go away if you add a call to `System.gc()` inside your code?

Comment: I mean does it stop listening as soon as `System.gc()` is called, if you arrange for it to be called a little later in your code (using Timer, Button, whatever)?

Comment: I called `System.gc()` in my Main class from a task scheduled to run at 5 minutes in the first attempt, then at 15 minutes in the second attempt. After testing it with a demo Arduino project, after the `System.gc()` call, the application still runs and receives data normally. I must mention that the app works fine with my demo Arduino application and the serial communication does not stop, but the maximum delay between messages is 32 seconds due to some Arduino limitations. When testing on the actual serial line at work, where delays can be larger, the issue described above appears.

Comment: OK I've setup a virtual serial ports pair with com0com, written a little receiver program with your code connected to one end, a little sender program also using jSerialComm sending a message every minute on the other end. Letting it run for a while, letting you know if something comes out of this

Comment: Code: https://www.jdoodle.com/a/3q6F

Comment: Thanks! I also moved the `comPort` variable from my code and declared it as final to make sure it isn't garbage collected, but after running for a few hours, the app stopped receiving data again.

Comment: I've made another version where messages can be sent up to 2 hours apart, holding no strong reference to anything, filling up memory with random strings, executing GC every 3 minutes. It's been running OK for 19 hours (on Java 8)... code and console outputs here jdoodle.com/a/3qfe

Comment: Same thing happens with my Arduino data transmission simulation, it works just fine. Also, when checking the data transmission with the Serial Port Monitor app on the serial port from work, the data is received normally, without stopping. That was tested for more than 24h. My app reads and holds 3 large `Map` objects with data read from excel files and at the moment uses around 1Gb of memory. This is still work in progress, but it shouldn't really be a problem as long as there's enough memory available, right?

Comment: I guess so. Anyway it should carry on working as long as you hold a strong reference to both the SerialPort and the MessageListener (to be clear I was trying to make it fail here). Maybe the problem is not in your Java code but in your serial port interface, but I think you're ruling this out with your serial port monitor, right? Or could it be interfering? I'm sorry but there's not much more I can do but keeping you posted on these tests...

Comment: I appreciate your help! I changed the type of communication event to `LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE` and I'm gonna test it tomorrow, I'll come back with an update if it works

Comment: FYI, I've stopped my test after 49 hours: it was still running fine. Logs in  the jDoodle. Sorry I couldn't help

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! I've been researching the problem and some say that the port loses communication due to the USB selective suspend setting on Windows 10, but after disabling it the issue still appears. The issue might also be due to the fact that my serial input comes from a splitter. I will keep researching the problem and will update this post once I come up with a solution.

Comment: Thanks for keeping me up to date! Hope you'll solve this quickly